# AJAX call to ASP service throws a 500 - what's missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a couple of web apps that work normally, but for some reason, this one is returning 500 errors whenever I call a function in my service.

Here is the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyData" connectionString="** Insert Connection String Here **" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
             connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
             applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <!-- system.serviceModel added by developers -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestJson">
          <enableWebScript />
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebTestBehavior">
          <!-- ** serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" / ** -->
          <!-- serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" / -->
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <!-- ** serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" / ** -->
          <!-- serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" / -->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicBinding">
          <!-- ** Change from "None" ** -->
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Web_Test.LoginService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="WebTestBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding"
                  name="RestJson" 
                  contract="Web_Test.LoginServiceInterface" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="RestJson">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Here is the Javascript code from my main .cshtml that calls the service:
    // userUsername and userPassword are string variables

```
var TestConnectionParams = [{"username": userUsername, "password": userPassword}];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LoginService.svc/TestConnection",
    data: JSON.stringify(TestConnectionParams),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var ReturnString = "Login returned " + data;
        $(OutputDiv).html(ReturnString);
    },
    error: function (HelpRequest, ErrorCode, TheError) {
        var ErrorMsg = "Login Failed:<br />" + TheError;
        $(OutputDiv).html(ErrorMsg);
    },
    async:false
});
```

And here is the service's .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Web_Test
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface LoginServiceInterface
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        String TestConnection(String username, String password);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class LoginService : LoginServiceInterface
    {
        public String TestConnection(String username, String password)
        {
            String ReturnString = "This didn't do anything";

            return ReturnString;
        }
    }
}
```

The AJAX call returns "Login Failed: Internal Server Error".

I am pretty sure I am missing something reasonably obvious in my web.config, but I can't see it.

Comment: What version of ASP/ASP.NET are you running?  Is this only locally or on your dev server?  What does the eventlog say?  Can you set a breakpoint on your server side code and hit anything?

Comment: I am running ASP.Net 4.0, locally on my client.
Fiddler shows that the JSON call appears to be sending the parameters properly; however, when I set a breakpoint to the first line of the TestConnection function in the .svc.cs file, it does not hit it.

Also, if I change the name of the function in the AJAX call, it returns a 500, but if I change the name of the service, it returns a 404 (Not Found), so I am assuming that it knows that the service itself exists.

Answer (score 1):

**THWACK** - gee, you don't think that the fact that the function in the service's .cs file is expecting two Strings while the AJAX call is sending it a one-element array (where the element consists of two strings) has something to do with it, do you?

For those of you who may have this problem in the future, the corrected .svc.cs is:

```
namespace Web_Test
{
    public struct TestConnectionParams
    {
        public String username;
        public String password;
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface LoginServiceInterface
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        String TestConnection(TestConnectionParams[] theParams);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class LoginService : LoginServiceInterface
    {
        public String TestConnection(TestConnectionParams[] theParams)
        {
            String ReturnString = "Username is '" + theParams[0].username + ' and Password is {wouldn't you like to know}";
            // actually, password is theParams[0].password
            return ReturnString;
        }
    }
}
```